# scaling factor for sw-XXXdp qualifier

Tags: android, android-studio, screen

is there any scaling factor for using in sw-XXXdp? i want my exactly look same in different screen sizes and densities.

for example for sw-480dp my value is 100dp what is it in sw-800dp? 100*?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `sw-XXXdp` is not a density qualifier, so you will not have any scaling taken in account, except if you combine it with a density qualifier (`hdpi`, `xhdpi`, etc).

As found on [Android developer's website](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali):

> The smallest width qualifier specifies the smallest of the screen's two sides, regardless of the device's current orientation, so it's a simple way to specify the overall screen size available for your layout.

The smallest width qualifier (`sw-XXXdp`) is just here to make sure that the screen will have a minimum size for your layout. For instance, it's good to use `sw-480dp` if you have a content that should be at least 400dp wide or high, so you still have space to add margins and have a good look and feel.

In the end, to your question:

> for example for sw-480dp my value is 100dp what is it in sw-800dp? 100*?

I would answer that you can follow proportional rules, so assuming you have `100dp` as a baseline (`mdpi`) for a `sw-480dp` screen, you should have around `166dp` for a `sw-800dp` screen and then adapt regarding the different densities.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote or mark as solution if this answer helped you.